# Clarification on Notation in Munkres Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, notation

I am reading Munkres Topology book and am trying to understand the proof of 83.1 (attached bellow)[image: 83.1]
On the second line it says "for each alpha...", my question is what is alpha? A point? An arc? I'm a bit confused and I can't seem to find a part where he specified in the text. Is this a notational convention that I should be familiar with. For background, here is the only definition proceeding the lemma in this chapter:[image: def]

Comment: It seems to me that there is an implicit index set present, so a more formal way would be to talk about a collection $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha \in I}$ with $I$ being some set. However, since the set used for indexing is more or less irrelevant, it is not mentioned. By definition, the index set is in bijection with the edges of $X$. (Note that $(1)$ should actually talk about intersections of distinct arcs).

Comment: Is there a bigger theorem stated before the lemma? It seems that there should be additional text surrounding the statement of the lemma. Evidently, there is some indexed family of sets $\{A_\alpha\}$ where $\alpha$ is in some indexing set.

Comment: Thank you! & no, I looked for a bigger theorem or additional text around the lemma and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Munkres's definition of a linear graph $X$ uses a given collection $A_\alpha$ of subspaces of $X$ with certain properties. As Matthias Klupsch comments, it is implicit here the indices $\alpha$ belong to some set $I$ (the *index set*). Perhaps is would have been better to say

> ... is a space $X$ that is written as the union of a collection $A_\alpha$, $\alpha \in I$, of subspaces ...

In the proof of Lemma 83.1 you should therefore understand

> For each $\alpha \in I$ ...

or

> For each edge of $X$ ...

An alternative definition could be this:

A *linear graph* is a space $X$ together with a set $\mathfrak A$ of subspaces of $X$, each of which is an arc, such that:

1. The intersection $A \cap A'$ of any two $A, A' \in \mathfrak A$ is either empty or consists of single point that is an end point of each.
2. The topology of $X$ is coherent with the subpaces $A \in \mathfrak A$.